# Primitive double value equal depends on magnitude?

Tags: java

I have to check to see whether two double values are equal including magnitude and precision. I encounter a weird scenario where primitive double equals check is not consistent and depend on magnitude of value.

Java version i've used:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My code:

```
public class Test{
     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
         String val1 = "15.999999999999999";
         String val2 = "16";
         String val3 = "16.999999999999999";
         String val4 = "17";
         double d1 = Double.parseDouble(val1);
         double d2 = Double.parseDouble(val2);
         double d3 = Double.parseDouble(val3);
         double d4 = Double.parseDouble(val4);
         System.out.println(val1 + "=" + val2 + "? ===>" + (d1==d2));
         System.out.println(val3 + "=" + val4 + "? ===>" + (d3==d4));
     }
}
```

Output:

```
15.999999999999999=16? ===>false
16.999999999999999=17? ===>true
```

Comment: That's not wierdness - the values representable are not always the same distance apart (it gets larger the farther you get from 0).  Eventually the difference becomes larger than an integral `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do won't work for various boring and complicated reasons that you can read about here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Unless you're going to compare the bit-representation of the doubles (which may or may not be insightful), you will always need some sort of epsilon value, i.e. margin of error when dealing with floating-point representations of numbers. Something like:

```
boolean doublesAreEqual(double d1, double d2)
{
    double d = d1 / d2;
    return (Math.abs(d - 1.0) < 0.00001 /* epsilon */);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response But this methods returns true for 16.9999 and 17 where as they are not equal. I want to check both magnitude and precision.

Comment: It worked as i increase epsilon. Our app should support up to 13digits as precision. (Math.abs(d - 1.0) < 0.000000000000001) works for us. thanks.

Comment: Like I mentioned, unless comparing bit-values is insightful to your problem, what you want to do can't be done. Raising the epsilon is really the best solution you can get in this case.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco your method returns false if we call `doublesAreEqual(0.0, 0.0);`

Comment: @Blip: A special check needs to be done for `(0.0,0.0)` as `0.0/0.0` will yield `NaN` or `+Infinity` per IEEE-754.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco I know the reason. I pointed it out so that it would be  better to note this condition in your answer for the benefit of all and also why not alter the method to accommodate this condition?

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are approximations. They have a finite set of discrete values possible. When you create a floating point number by parsing a string, the closest possible floating point value is selected to represent it.

The double closest to 15.999999999999999 is 15.999999999999998, not 16.0, so that comparison is unequal. But 17.0 is the closest double to 16.999999999999999, so they compare equal.

Comment: The double closest to 15.999999999999999 is 15.999999999999998 not 16.0 hence they are not equal, why not the closest to 16.999999999999999 is 16.999999999999998 not 17.0?

Comment: @Murthy - Because we are thinking in decimal, instead of binary. Remember that we have to use sums of fractions where the denominator is a power of two to make the decimal part. So, the possible values are 16.999999999999996 or 17.0. You can see that 17.0 is closer in this case. I'd have to work it out, but you might see a similar loss in precision as you move past 32, since the whole number part would then need 6 bits instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

dont use == when comparing double or float values.

instead use Double.compare  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

and Float.compare for floats.

Comment: `Double.compare(a,b)` returns 0 if and only if `a==b` so it would still be the same issue

Comment: Yes the same problem occurred with this approach, it again depends on magnitude of the double value. worked for 15.999999999999999 and 16 but not for 16.999999999999999 and 17.