# Doubles from oracle and java with same value unequal

Tags: java, oracle

I have a scenario from production where two doubles, one from java and one from Oracle with the same values do not satisfy java's == for double.

Oracle's double :

```
double amt = rs.getDouble("amount"); //toString() yeilds 60773.0
```

Java's double :

```
String amt2 = "₹ 60,773.00".replace(",", "").replace("\u20b9 ", "");
```

Equality validation :

```
if(!(Double.parseDouble(amt2)==amt))
{
    syso("Mismatch");
}
```

I am using java 1.6.0_33 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primitive double value equal depends on magnitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668954/primitive-double-value-equal-depends-on-magnitude)

Comment: Use `BigDecimal`, and `compareTo()` instead...

Comment: try `Double.compare()`

Comment: @Tom but if you see in that question, the scenario is totally different and can be simulated in the same environment. Mine on the other hand could not be simulated at my end but this happened in production.

Comment: The other _question_ doesn't matter, what matters are the _answers_ there. They tell you that double (or float) comparison can be inaccurate and how to compare such values in a proper way.

Comment: @Tom I am sorry but i do not want to take any chance while finding the root cause. So, in my case there is no precision as far as my two doubles are considered, going by the answers there, it was based on the fractional part that causes the issue. In my case, one is 60733.0 (rs.getDouble("60733")) and other is 60733.00 (Double.parseDouble("60733.00")) and with no fractional part other than zeroes. This is the main reason why i am skeptical also, i could not replicate the issue with the same dataset at my end.